# ¿Como pausar y reproducir un vídeo mediante eventos?

Tags: javascript, eventos

Estoy mirando como pausar un vídeo y volver a reproducirlo, si doy a `space bar`  se pausa, okay, pero ahora que es `true` debería volver a reproducirse,  no? No se como es.

```js
var space = false;
 body.onkeydown = function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 32 && space == false) {
   space = true;
   video.pause();
  }
 }

 body.onkeydown = function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 32 && space == true) {
   video.play();
   space = false;
  }
```

Comment: Te hace falta un video de prueba para que se pueda probar tu código. Te sugiero poner uno de [aquí](http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5).

Answer (score 2):

Ibas muy bien casi lo logras, solo tenías un pequeño error de lógica ya que no necesitas dos eventos y dos funciones para controlar tu video, utilizando un solo evento que desencadene una función la cual contenga una condición de que hacer en caso de que la variable sea `true` o `false` es suficiente.

Ejemplo funcional:

```js
var body = document.body;
var video = document.querySelector("#video");

var space = false;

body.onkeydown = function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 32 && !space) {
        space = true;
        video.pause();
    }else if(e.keyCode == 32 && space){
        space = false;
        video.play();
    }
}
```

```html
<video preload autoplay id="video">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Debería estar dentro del mismo evento ya que así se reproduce y pausea al mismo tiempo. Algo así:

```
var space = false;
body.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        if (space) {
            space = false;
            return video.play();
        } else {
            space = true;
            return video.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que existen en tu ejemplo es que estas pisando la primer función asignada a `body.onkeydown` cuando agregas la segunda.

### Solución:

1. Para evitar este tipo de problemas deberías usar [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), el cual te permite agregar mas de un `listener` a un evento puntual sobre un elemento.
2. En este caso puntual podrías meter toda la lógica en un mismo función (o `listener`)
3. No deberías usar [`e.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) ya que esta deprecado.

### Demo:

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");
var paused = false;
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.key !== ' ') return; // Si no es espacio, no hacemos nada
  video[paused ? 'play' : 'pause']();
  paused = !paused;
});
```

```html
<video preload autoplay id="video">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```